How to get the current block element (e.g., h1, h2, p, etc.) where the cursor is in Jodit editor?
I’m using Jodit editor in my project and need to figure out which block element the cursor is currently in. For example, if the cursor is inside a h1, h2, or p tag, I want to identify that block and perform some custom actions based on it.
Does Jodit provide any built-in method to get the block element where the cursor is located? If not, what would be a good way to achieve this in the Jodit editor? Any help or code snippet would be appreciated!
Example Use Case
When the cursor is inside an h2 tag, I’d like to get the information that the current block is h2. This will allow me to adjust the toolbar or apply specific styles depending on the block type.
I am using React Typescript
I was expecting to find a way to get the block-level parent element (e.g., h1, h2, p) of the current cursor position.
